# How to update the panel after removing items in sencha

Tags: extjs

I am using sencha to update a panel as follows.
I will have a handler for a button. 
In that i am removing a docked panel from a panel. and then adding the some new panel as a docked item.
But the contents of the panel are not appearing. They are appearing only when i change the size of the browser window, i.e., maximize it or restore it.
How can the problem be solved?
The code for the problem is as shown below.

```
 handler: function(){
        chaptersPanel.removeDocked(chaptersList[chaptersPanel.getStory()]);
        chaptersPanel.insertDocked(0,chaptersList[this.no]);
        chaptersPanel.setStory(this.no);
        chaptersPanel.doLayout();
        mainPanel.setActiveItem("chaptersPanel");   
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu need to do a doComponentLayout() sometimes. Sencha Touch is a little flakey about it. doLayout is supposed to handle the componentlayout, but it doesn't always